# Some NGit stuff prevents C# application from shutting down correctly

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, git

I am trying to use [NGit library](https://github.com/slluis/ngit) in my application (C#, MS.NET 4.0). As we are on MS platform I have rebuilt the NGit for .NET Framework 4.0 under VS 2010. Most things are good and all the functionality works well but the application hangs on its shutdown. VS Debugger shows that some thread from Sharpen lib stays infinitely in the waiting state and nobody signals it to shutdown. That happens when I use any of the instance methods of `NGit.Api.Git` class (for static methods things seem to be OK). Did anybody experience such issues? Any suggestions?

Example of code using `Git` class:

```
Git myrepo = Git.Init().SetDirectory(@"C:\myrepo.git").SetBare(true).Call();
FetchResult fetchResult = myrepo.Fetch()
    .SetProgressMonitor(new TextProgressMonitor())
    .SetRemote(@"C:\projects\initialrepo")
    .SetRefSpecs(new RefSpec("refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master"))
    .Call();
//
// Some other work...
//
myrepo.GetRepository().Close();
```

And here is the place where the thread hangs:

Class `Sharpen.ThreadExecutor`, line 9 below (`St.Monitor.Wait (pendingTasks)`):

```
public void RunPoolThread ()
{
    while (!IsTerminated ()) {
        try {
            Runnable r = null;
            lock (pendingTasks) {
                freeThreads++;
                while (!IsTerminated () && pendingTasks.Count == 0)
                    ST.Monitor.Wait (pendingTasks);
                if (IsTerminated ())
                    break;
                r = pendingTasks.Dequeue ();
            }
            if (r != null)
                r.Run ();
        }
        catch (ST.ThreadAbortException) {
            ST.Thread.ResetAbort ();
        }
        catch {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps post minimal example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Sounds like you should do some more research on how to use the NGit library.

Comment: I've added examples of the code if it can help.

Comment: That should hang, it is even abort-proof.  Find out how to pulse the pendingTasks lock and get IsTerminated() to return true.  There ought to be some kind of public method that does that.

Comment: Sure thing. But all this threading stuff is internal or even private and it is not visible from outside code. I tried to find any public connectors to there but I'm unsuccessful yet...

Comment: @Hans: did you have a look? If not, better not voice so loudly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did get the library and ran the tests. I found some of the relevant tests to fail intermittently. I don't know if the  test cases are wrong or whether there is an actual problem.

I reported the issue here: https://github.com/slluis/ngit/issues/8

I'll have a look at the particular code you added, I've just seen it

---

I tested the following code on

1. Linux (Mono 2.6.7, .NET 3.5)
2. Linux (Mono 2.11, .NET 4.0)

The problem appears to be that the static `BatchingProgressMonitor` (which is *also* constructed when you do not register the `TextProgressMonitor`) is never 'destructed', meaning that the alarmQueue with it's associated thread-pool is never `Shutdown`.

If you add the following public method to the class `BatchingProgressMonitor`:

```
public static void ShutdownNow()
{
    alarmQueue.ShutdownNow();
}
```

you can have a 'workaround' by calling `BatchingProgressMonitor.ShutdownNow()` before exiting your application. This *WorkedForMe*<sup>TM</sup>. The sample code shows how to do that when you remove the `#if/#endif`.

.

```
using System;
using NGit;
using NGit.Api;
using NGit.Transport;

namespace Stacko
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Git myrepo = Git.Init().SetDirectory(@"/tmp/myrepo.git").SetBare(true).Call();
            {
                var fetchResult = myrepo.Fetch()
                    .SetProgressMonitor(new TextProgressMonitor())
                    .SetRemote(@"/tmp/initial")
                    .SetRefSpecs(new RefSpec("refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master"))
                    .Call();
                //
                // Some other work...
                //
                myrepo.GetRepository().Close();
            }
            System.GC.Collect();

#if false
            System.Console.WriteLine("Killing");
            BatchingProgressMonitor.ShutdownNow();
#endif
            System.Console.WriteLine("Done");

        }
    }
}
```

I'll report this at the issue tracker too. **Edit** Done: [here](https://github.com/mono/ngit/issues/9)

Cheers,
Seth

Comment: Thanks `@sehe`!  I am looking forward to your response.

Comment: @Dmitry Zorin: Think I found the cause, and have provided _feeble_ workaround. This shouldn't really be needed, and I don't suggest you use it for any serious work, but still, it demonstrates that calling ShutdownNow _would solve the hang_

Comment: `@sehe:` Thank you very much. You confirmed my suspicions about the source of the error and that there is no public stuff for its handling. Yes, your workaround works well on my environment (Windows 7 x64, MS.NET Framework 4.0) but you're right, it's just a workaround. This should be handled somehow on the library level. Thank you for reporting those issues and a lot of thanks for your participation, it is really helpful.

Comment: `These issues have been fixed as far as I can tell. You shouldn't need to explicitly shut down the threads anymore. Please re-open the issue if you can reproduce hangs/deadlocks with the latest translated code.` - [Alan McGovernm here](https://github.com/mono/ngit/issues/9#issuecomment-6764280) and [here](https://github.com/mono/ngit/issues/8#issuecomment-6764231)

Comment: Cool!  Thanks again @sehe for your very helpful participation!